# .pfx password issue C#

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, passwords, pfx

A new topic too me is file extension .pxf security. Even though I get the password, I don't know how to use them. How does this work on .NET programming? Especially unlocking pfx-secured assemblies.

Assignments are submitted as compressed solutions. Normally, I unzip files and open them using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out there are different techniques to solve this issue.

1. Find the .pfx file using explorer in the assemply-project. right-click the .pfx file and choose install.pfx. When asked - enter the password - and it works imediately
2. If you have the source code project, you can uncheck the "Sign the assembly" checkbox, which you find of you double-click the Properties within the assembly.